# Pass values to parent component with eventemitter

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

How could i send the value of 'mytoki' from my modal component to its parent ?

I'm not sure if i should create another EventEmitter or a service. Any suggestions ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output()
  toHide = new EventEmitter();

  private usrname;
  private pswd;
  private visible: string;
  private mytoki;

  constructor(private loginservice: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  connect(usrname, pswd) {
    this.loginservice.getUserLogin(this.usrname, this.pswd).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.mytoki = response.headers.get('Authorization');
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', this.mytoki);
        console.log('Connected');
      }, err => {
        // TODO
        // login errors
        // put token into nav component
      }, () => {
          this.visible = 'hide';
          this.toHide.emit(this.visible);
          this.usrname = '';
          this.pswd = '';
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Many ways to do, for example with a return value

Comment: @BertVerhees My 'toHide eventemitter' already contains a string value, what am i trying to achieve is sending the value of 'mytoki' too, but not sure how to do it

Comment: See the answer from Kellie below, that is a good way to handle it, another way is to create a helper class to hold the values to return, and return the helper-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `@Output() myTokiDetails;` on the modal component

Then for example after you set your sessionStorage do `this.myTokiDetails.emit(this.mytoki)`this will broadcast up the event and assuming you used a selector to add this to the parent you would on this modals selector: `<app-modal (myTokiDetails)="parentComponentFunction($event)"></app-modal>`